# Click on thumbnail and route to Controller method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I written a view that display a table listing of thumbnails. It is working now. Next I am writing another view, which display a new view with detailed information of the 
item thumbnail which was clicked. Right now, I am not sure how to add the information which makes the thumbmail clickable that routes to the GetDetailInfo Controller method 
that return a detailed information view.

Here is my thumbnail table list code:

```
    <table class="table-responsive" width="100%">
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var productGroup in Model.Select((e, i) => new { Product = e, Grouping = (i / 4) }).GroupBy(e => e.Grouping))
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var product in productGroup)
                    {
                        <td>
                            <div><br /></div>
                            <img src=@product.Product.Thumbnail style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
                            <div><br /></div>                               
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my the Controller method which I am writing which is called when the thumbnail is click and return a detailed view.

```
    [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Item Detail", ParentKey = "Item-Home", Key = "Item-Detail", PreservedRouteParameters = "itemId")]
    [Route("~/item/{itemId}/detail")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetDetailInfo(int itemId)
    {
        var result = await ItemService.GetDetailInfo(contentId) );

        return View(result.Dto);
    }
```

I am not sure how to route the click on thumnbnail to this controller method to return a new detail info view. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The thumbnail is a link, right?  `<a href="@Url.Action("GetDetailInfo", "Controller", new { itemId = product.Product.Id })">/* Thumbnail Code Here */</a>`

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways to make an image as a link.

**1 - Using a link tag.**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetDetailInfo", "Controller", new { itemId = product.Product.Id })"> 
    <img src="@product.Product.Thumbnail" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
</a>
```

**2 - Using  a custom Html Helper**

Source:

```
public MvcHtmlString ActionImage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                                 string controller, 
                                 string action, 
                                 object routeValues, 
                                 string imagePath, 
                                 string alternateText = "", 
                                 object htmlAttributes = null)
{

  var anchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
  var url = new UrlHelper(HtmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

  anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href",url.Action(action,controller,routeValues));

  var imgBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
  imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", url.Content(imagePath));
  imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("alt", alternateText);

  var attributes = (IDictionary<string, object>) HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
  imgBuilder.MergeAttributes(attributes);
  string imgHtml = imgBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

  anchorBuilder.InnerHtml = imgHtml;
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Using:

```
@Html.ActionImage("Controller", "GetDetailInfo", new { itemId = @product.Product.Id }, "@product.Product.Thumbnail", "alternateText")
```

[Asp.Net MVC Html Helper to create link with an image](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-html-helper-to-create-link-with-an-image)

The first method is handy - and rightly commented by Bardicer in your question, - but the second one is more practical.